# Can I override Dictionary's Equals method?

Tags: c#, dictionary, overriding, equality

I want to override Dictionary's Equals method with `return d1.Count == d2.Count && !d1.Except(d2).Any();`

But I wanna do it for all the Dictionaries, and not just a specific type at a time.
I currently have a `public static bool IsEqualTo(this Dictionary<string, byte> d1, Dictionary<string, byte> d2)` method in my ExtensionMethods class, but it's neither generic (working with any KeyValuePairs), neither does it actually override the default "Equals" method.

Is there any way I can do this, or am I stuck to using what I currently have (perhaps I could at least make it a bit more generic with a template)?

Comment: Pass it a custom equality comparer.

Comment: Overrides are only relevant for derived classes. You cannot change the rules of equality for existing types. Per CodeCaster, write a custom equality comparer; most things that compare for equality accept a comparer instead (and those that don't should probably be rewritten anyway). If all else fails you can have a custom implementation of `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` (or even derive from `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`), but of course that's of no use if code is explicitly instantiating `Dictionary` or calling `.ToDictionary`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use your own custom ruls for `Equality`, you can implement `IEqualityComparer<T>` as CodeCaster suggested in the comments:

```
public sealed class DictionaryComparer<K, V> : IEqualityComparer<IDictionary<K, V>> {
  public bool Equals(IDictionary<K, V>? left, IDictionary<K, V>? right) {
    if (ReferenceEquals(left, right))
      return true;
    if (left is null || right is null)
      return false;

    return left.Count == right.Count && !left.Except(right).Any();
  }

  public int GetHashCode(IDictionary<K, V> value) => 
    value is null ? 0 : value.Count; 
}
```

Then whenever you want to compare two dictionaries:

```
Dictionary<int, string> dict1 = ...
Dictionary<int, string> dict2 = ...

if (new DictionaryComparer<int, string>().Equals(dict1, dict2)) {
  //TODO: relevant code here
}
```

You can implement an *extension method* if you like:

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions {
  public static bool EqualsToDictionary<K, V>(this IDictionary<K, V> left,
                                                   IDictionary<K, V> right) {
    var comparer = new DictionaryComparer<K, V>();

    return compare.Equals(left, right);
  }
}
```

then

```
Dictionary<int, string> dict1 = ...
Dictionary<int, string> dict2 = ...

if (dict1.EqualsToDictionary(dict2)) {
  //TODO: relevant code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply make make your `IsEqualTo` method generic?

```cs
public static bool IsEqualTo<K, V>(this IDictionary<K, V> d1, IDictionary<K, V> d2)
{
    return d1.Count == d2.Count && !d1.Except(d2).Any();
}
```

By extending `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>` instead of `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` we can apply the extension method to other types of dictionaries like `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>` or `SortedDictionary<TKey,TValue>` and many more.

Note that C# can infer the generic type parameters:

```cs
var d1 = new Dictionary<string, byte>();
var d2 = new Dictionary<string, byte>();
var s1 = new SortedDictionary<int, string>();
var s2 = new SortedDictionary<int, string>();

// Not necessary to specify the generic type parameters.
bool result1 = d1.IsEqualTo(d2);
bool result2 = s1.IsEqualTo(s2);
```

Comment: I hadn't made it generic before making this post mostly because I only had 1 use-case in my code and I was mostly wondering how to do the overriding part. However, now I have indeed made it generic :P